# Removing or changing src of images by jQuery does not abort the loading request

Tags: jquery, image, loading, onload

I am working on a blog which will contain a lot of photos, for this reason I want to prevent the images to load until i say them to.

There are images in the HTML code (the preview images) and some that I will add later with jQuery (for example to enlarge the preview images).

I had no trouble with handling the images added by jQuery, because i stored the images for preloading in a seperated container and just added the "src" attribute with the **.on('load', function(){})** to the real image when the preload image finished loading.

For the images which are in the HTML code I tried the same. After DOM ready I iterate through them and remove the src-Tag by **.attr('src', '')** but which will not prevent the images from loading and blocks me all the traffic. I even tested removing every image on DOM ready with **$('img').remove()**, but Firebug and Chrome element inspector still show the network traffic caused by loading all these images.

So my question is: Does the removing src attribute hack not work on images defined in the HTML code? Is there a posibility to stop loading these images? Isn't the order of requests first loading the HTML, then applying the js code and then get the image requests?

Do I otherwise need to regulate this through ajax requests (what i want to avoid)?

The website I do refer to (Link to a post with images):
http://www.pablosichert.de/blog/#/UID17

Comment: The DOM ready event doesn't run until after the HTML has been loaded, and the IMG loading is queued up during the initial load. So it's too late to stop it.

Comment: I could fix it by using the window.stop() command, but this is a really dirty fix and with that I would have to re-initiate loading everything that was stopped by that. I guess I better make it clean and use ajax.

Comment: Even when I get the data by ajax, I cant prevent the images defined in the HTML from loading.

Comment: If you don't want the images to load, why are they in the HTML in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar because my CMS puts them into the HTML. I just want to get them loaded in another order for images with higher priority. On first load I now just installed a progress bar, which will indicate the images left to be loaded.